# Compress a number as a string to fit in 256 char space

Tags: ruby, string, memory, compression, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to use a bitmask to provide as many binary values as possible so that the final value will store in the limited allocate memory for a string. My current methodology is to find a maximum number and convert it to a string base-36.

```
value = (0 | (1<<1318)).to_s(36)
```

The result is 255 chars of a compressed number from which I can extract my original number of 1318. The downside is I'm limited to 1,318 binary values and I want to expand that number. Are there any alternative strategies in Ruby to compress this number even further?

Comment: Does it have to be base 36? Base 64, 85, or "raw bytes" are of course all higher density

Comment: It doesn't have to be base 36, that's just the current solution I'm at.

Comment: @Harold, note that `n <= 36` in `to_s(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always encode your number into base `s` and then represent that as string with whatever alphabet you want.

```
def encode(n, alphabet)
  s = alphabet.size
  res = []
  while (n > 0)
    res << n % s
    n = n / s
  end
  res.reverse.map { |i| alphabet[i] }.join
end
```

Your method is then equivalent to `encode(n, alphabet)`, where `alphabet` is defined as

```
alphabet = ((0..9).to_a + ("a".."z").to_a).join
# => "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

But you might as well use all possible characters instead of only 36 of them:

```
extended_alphabet = (0..255).map { |i| i.chr }.join
```

This gives a total of (256 ** 255) possibilities, i.e. up to (2 ** 2040), which is much better than your actual (2 ** 1318).

This encoding happens to be optimal because each character of your string can have at most 256 different values, and all of them are used here.

---

Decoding can then be performed as follows:

```
def decode(encoded, alphabet)
  s = alphabet.size
  n = 0
  decode_dict = {}; i = -1
  alphabet.each_char { |c| decode_dict[c] = (i += 1) }
  encoded.each_char do |c|
    n = n * s + decode_dict[c]
  end
  n
end
```

If you are going to use a fixed alphabet for all your encodings, I would suggest computing the decoding dictionnary outside of the function and taking it as a parameter instead of `alphabet`, to  avoid computing it every time you try to encode a number.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is interesting. Assuming my `n` represents the largest number I can store as a string prior to encoding, this method increases my binary slots from 1318 to around 2035. That's definitely an improvement. In other words, `encode((0 | (1<<2035)), extended_alphabet).length` gives me 255. What would the decode method look like? Is there a way to get this number up by a lot more?

Comment: I added the decoding function. Note that I also reversed the encoding to make the decoding simpler. You can encode numbers from 0 to ((1 << 2040) - 1) included with this method. It is impossible to encode more numbers into 255 characters for the mathematical reason quoted above, so this is as high as you can get, but if you allow more than 255 chars, the encoding will still work and you will have more possibilities

Comment: Also, ( 0 | ( 1 << 2035) ) is the same as ( 1 << 2035 ), so there is no need to add this "zero or" prefix. It is also equivalent to ( 2 ** 2035 ), which might be easier to read

Answer (score 1):

**Numbers are non-negative**

If the numbers are non-negative we can encode each 8-bits of each number to a character that is part of a string, and then decode the string by converting each character to 8 bits of the number.

```
def encode(n)
  str = ''
  until n.zero?
    str << (n & 255).chr
    n = n >> 8
  end
  str.reverse
end

def decode(str)     
  str.each_char.reduce(0) { |n,c| (n << 8) | c.ord }
end
```

This uses the following bit-manipulation methods in the class [Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html): `&`, `>>`, `<<` and `|`.

```
def test(n)
  encoded = encode(n)
  puts "#{n} => #{encoded} => #{decode(encoded)}"
end

test      1  #      1 => ["\u0001"]            =>      1
test     63  #     63 => ["?"]                 =>     63
test     64  #     64 => ["@"]                 =>     64
test    255  #    255 => ["\xFF"]              =>    255
test    256  #    256 => ["\u0001", "\u0000"]  =>    256
test 123456  # 123456 => ["\x01", "\xE2", "@"] => 123456
```

For example,

```
n = 123456
n.to_s(2)
  #=> "11110001001000000"
```

so

```
n = 0b11110001001000000
  #=> 123456
```

The bytes of this number can be visualized so:

```
00000001 11100010 01000000
```

We see that

```
a = [0b00000001, 0b11100010, 0b01000000]
a.map(&:chr)
  #=> ["\x01", "\xE2", "@"]
```

**Numbers can be negative**

If the numbers to be encoded can be negative we need to first convert then to their absolute values then add some information to the encoded string that indicates whether they are non-negative or negative. That will require at least one additional byte so we might include a `"+"` for non-negative numbers and a `"-"` for negative numbers.

```
def encode(n)
  sign = "+"
  if n < 0
    sign = "-"
    n = -n
  end
  str = ''
  until n.zero?
    str << (n & 255).chr
    n = n >> 8
  end
  (str << sign).reverse
end

def decode(str)
  n = str[1..-1].each_char.reduce(0) { |n,c| (n << 8) | c.ord }
  str[0] == '+' ? n : -n
end

test    -255  # -255    => ["-", "\xFF"]              => -255
test    -256  # -256    => ["-", "\u0001", "\u0000"]  => -256
test -123456  # -123456 => ["-", "\x01", "\xE2", "@"] => -123456
test  123456  #  123456 => ["+", "\x01", "\xE2", "@"] =>  123456
```